# how to run command line arguments with users having special characters in their usernames?

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio-code, error-handling

I am trying to use VS Code and installing python extension , somewhere in b/w a msg pops out and says to install linter .

When I try to do that an error is thrown .[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeOiG.png)

Actually , at the time of installation of windows 10 , I entered  "$parsh" as my username, I didn't expected at that time using a special character could cause a problem to me.

Now how to solve this issue.

Comment: Hi, we canot see the full path to the modules traversed by the traceback in your screenshot. This could help. Anyway. This seems that the error is raised from a standard module/package, the immediate solution is changing your usename to something more "classical" using only ASCII letters (a-z)

Comment: changing the username in windows is not easy I guess . Changing the username User Accounts Settings won't change the directory name form C:\Users\Username .